# Highlighting two navigation items with <body id>

Tags: css, navigation

I've read through the forums and have not been able to find a question similar enough to mine for me to fix my website, so I hope someone can help.

I'm building a website for my local school which has a top navigation and a left side navigation. I've written the top navigation as a list and styled in CSS and use Body ID to highlight the navigation item of the page I'm on, that all works great and I'm going to move that to an include in PHP so I've only got one file to update for that.

On each of the sub categories though, I have a side navigation, which is currently manually programmed and manually highlighted, but I'd like to be able to do the same as the top navigation, have a list navigation and have something like Body ID which automatically highlights the left navigation item when it knows it's on the right page. I've tried adding two Body IDs and this didn't work. Is there a smarter way to do it?

Here's my test site which is work in progress at the moment. 
http://www.antbird.net/school/

Thanks very much, I appreciate any help I can get.

Ant

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one `ID` for each element.

However, you can use that `<body id=" ">` when setting the left nav.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I'm not quite sure how that would work though, How could I tie in the top nav and left nav at the same time using one body ID with multiple pages under the one section? Is there a better way to do it perhaps?